# Parsing chemical compounds in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I was trying to make a chemical compound parser as an exercise for myself but I got stuck.

Here is the data type I am trying to use:

```
data Compound = Monoatomic String Int | Poliatomic [Compound] Int
```

Given a string like "Ca(OH)2", I want to get something like;

```
Poliatomic [Monoatomic "Ca" 1, Poliatomic [Monoatomic "O" 1, Monoatomic "H" 1] 2 ] 1
```

Monoatomic type constructor for single atoms, and Poliatomic constructor for multiple atoms. In this example (OH)2 represents and inner Poliatomic structure and it is represented as `Poliatomic [(Monoatomic O 1), (Monoatomic H 1 )] 2`. The number `2` represents that we have two of those poliatomic structures.

I did this much;

```
import Data.Char (isUpper)
data Compound = Monoatomic String Int | Poliatomic [Compound] Int

instance Functor Compound where
        fmap f (Monoatomic s i) = Monoatomic (f s) i
        fmap f (Poliatomic xs i) = Poliatomic (fmap f xs) i

-- Change number of a compound
changeNumber :: Compound -> Int -> Compound
changeNumber (Monoatomic xs _) n = Monoatomic xs n
changeNumber (Poliatomic xs _) n = Poliatomic xs n

-- Take a partial compound and next chracter return partial compound
parseCompound :: Compound -> Char -> Compound
parseCompound (Poliatomic x:xs n) c
        | isUpper c = Poliatomic ((Monoatomic [c] 1):x:xs) n -- add new atom to compound
        | isLower c = Poliatomic 

-- I want to do foldl parseCompound (Poliatomic [] 1) inputstring
```

but then it got too complicated for me to continue.

It looks like it should be a fairly simple problem, but I am very new to Haskell and can't figure out how to complete this function.

I have this questions:

- Is my approach correct so far?
- How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you aware of parser combinators such as [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) and [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec)? These really help to ease writing parsers! I do realize you might want to do something entirely on your own for something this size, though.

Comment: I have just heard them but I don't know how to use them, or what exactly they do

Comment: There is a nice [pdf](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/parsec/parsec.pdf) and you can always look [at the haskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec) (bot some links there are broken by now)

Comment: Representing elements strings is a bit strange. An atom is described by its atomic number and mass number. An ion is described by its atomic number, mass number, and charge. The *name* of an atom is something for parsing and displaying, not for the internal representation. `data Element = Element {atomicNumber::Int, massNumber::Int}` and `data Ion = Ion {getElement::Element, getCharge::Int}` should get the basic idea across; it would be better to indicate positivity in the types when appropriate, but Haskell isn't so good for that.

Comment: Er ... actually, I guess you'd need `Element` with just atomic number and `Isotope` with element and mass number. Substances are essentially `Map`s from elements to numbers; there's no immediate need to distinguish monatomic from molecular substances.

Comment: Something different: `Compound` surely isn't a functor. That instance shouldn't even compile, IMO -- the type has the wrong shape (aka [kind](https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind)).

Comment: Depending on how deep into this you want to get, I strongly recommend this book (PDF) on Grammars and Parsing: http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gont/diktaat.pdf it's fairly lengthy, full of theory and a lot of exercises/problems with solutions as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created the parser you are looking for with [Parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) to give you a sense of what Parsec parsers look like, since you stated you had little experience with it.

Even with little Haskell experience, it should be fairly readable. I have provided some comments on the parts where there's something in particular to look out for.

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Text.Parsec (parse, many, many1, digit, char, string, (<|>), choice, try)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)


data Compound
  = Monoatomic String Int
  | Poliatomic [Compound] Int
  deriving Show


-- Run the substance parser on "Ca(OH)2" and print the result which is
-- Right (Poliatomic [Monoatomic "Ca" 1,Poliatomic [Monoatomic "O" 1,Monoatomic "H" 1] 2] 1)
main = print (parse substance "" "Ca(OH)2")


-- parse the many parts which make out the top-level polyatomic compound
--
-- "many1" means "at least one"
substance :: Parser Compound
substance = do
  topLevel <- many1 part
  return (Poliatomic topLevel 1)


-- a single part in a substance is either a poliatomic compound or a monoatomic compound
part :: Parser Compound
part = poliatomic <|> monoatomic


-- a poliatomic compound starts with a '(', then has many parts inside, then
-- ends with ')' and has a number after it which indicates how many of it there
-- are.
poliatomic :: Parser Compound
poliatomic = do
  char '('
  inner <- many1 part
  char ')'
  amount <- many1 digit
  return (Poliatomic inner (read amount))


-- a monoatomic compound is one of the many element names, followed by an
-- optional digit. if omitted, the amount defaults to 1.
--
-- "try" is a little special, and required in this case. it means "if a parser
-- fails, try the next one from where you started, not from where the last one
-- failed."
--
-- "choice" means "try all parsers in this list, stop when one matches"
--
-- "many" means "zero or more"
monoatomic :: Parser Compound
monoatomic = do
  name <- choice [try nameParser | nameParser <- atomstrings]
  amount <- many digit
  return (Monoatomic name (fromMaybe 1 (readMaybe amount)))


-- a list of parser for atom names. it is IMPORTANT that the longest names
-- come first. the reason for that is that it makes the parser much simpler to
-- write, and it can execute much faster. it's common when designing parsers to
-- consider things like that when creating them.
atomstrings :: [Parser String]
atomstrings = map string (words "He Li Be Ne Na Mg Al Ca H B C N O F")
```

I've tried to write this code in a way that should be at least reasonably accessible to a beginner, but it's probably not crystal clear so I'm happy to answer any questions about this.

---

The parser above is the one you wanted. However, it's not the one I would write if I had free reins. If I got to do however I wanted, I would exploit the fact that

```
Ca(OH)2
```

can be represented as

```
(Ca)1((O)1(H)1)2
```

which is a much more uniform representation, and in turns results in a simpler data structure and a parser with less boilerplate. The code I'd prefer to write would look like

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>), pure)
import Text.Parsec (parse, many, many1, digit, char, string, (<|>), choice, try, between)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)


data Substance
  = Part [Substance] Int
  | Atom String
  deriving Show


main = print (parse substance "" "Ca(OH)2")
-- Right (Part [Part [Atom "Ca"] 1,Part [Part [Atom "O"] 1,Part [Atom "H"] 1] 2] 1)

substance :: Parser Substance
substance = Part <$> many1 part <*> pure 1

part :: Parser Substance
part = do
  inner <- polyatomic <|> monoatomic
  amount <- fromMaybe 1 . readMaybe <$> many digit
  return (Part inner amount)

polyatomic :: Parser [Substance]
polyatomic = between (char '(') (char ')') (many1 part)

monoatomic :: Parser [Substance]
monoatomic = (:[]) . Atom <$> choice (map (try . string) atomstrings)

atomstrings :: [String]
atomstrings = words "He Li Be Ne Na Mg Al Ca H B C N O F"
```

This uses a few "advanced" tricks in Haskell (such as the `<$>` and `<*>` operators) so might not be of interest to you, OP, but I'm putting it in for other people who might be more advanced Haskell users and learning about Parsec.

This parser takes only about half a page, as you see, and that's the power of libraries like Parsec – they make it both easy and *fun* to write parsers!